# "li.menuItem:first" to "li.menuItem:second"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

On page load, the javascript makes the first thumbnail active, but i would like to change it to the second, third or even fourth thumbnail depending on the page that it is loading.

The javascript works for first thumbnail as active:

```
$('#menu ul li.menuItem:first').addClass('act').siblings().addClass('inact');
/* On page load, mark the first thumbnail as active */
```

i've tried changing it to:

```
$('#menu ul li.menuItem:second').addClass('act').siblings().addClass('inact');
```

but didnt work..what is the proper code for changing it to second, third, fourth etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector...

```
$('#menu ul li.menuItem:eq(2)')
```

Keep in mind that `:eq()` is 0 based.

Answer (score 2):

`li-menuItem:nth-child(3)` will select the 3rd menu item

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:eq` selector

`:eq(0)`  is equivalent to `:first`
`:eq(1)`  is like doing :second (what you want)

So your code would be:

```
$('#menu ul li.menuItem:eq(1)')   //This selects the second item
```

Hope this helps. Cheers